# How to identify to mysql console in AWS?

Tags: mysql, aws

I'm newbie in AWS but I have created a RDS mysql database and I can update it from MysqlWorkbench from my laptop. However, I would like to do it from mysql console in AWS.

First, I have uploaded an script to my AWS instance to loaded later when I will login in mysql console.

Exactly, I would like to do what I do in my local database:

```
$ mysql -u user-name -p
$ password: *******
```

But when I use this command *$ mysql -u user-name -p* in AWS I've got this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I load an script in AWS through mysql console?

Comment: If it's on RDS, why haven't you specified the hostname?

Comment: Yes, I't son RDS. I have no specified the hostname because in my laptop I don't do it :S I have to say that I try to access to mysql console being in AWS not from my laptop. I guess I have to specify the hostname ... Am I right?